# Ajax returns the request result to the whole screen rather than the designated textarea

Tags: php, ajax

This ajax test should (by the will of about 2 hours now) return the request result into a textarea. The request is being made to the same page, and I have a $_POST isset test at the top of the body to check whether the request is coming from my POST request (I need to have the code all in one file). The result is that "text to appear in the textarea box" is returned by itself, and isn't placed inside the textarea.

```
//name of this page is testing.php  

<html>
<head>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("testTextarea").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.open("POST","testing.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("test");
}

</head>

<?
if (isset($_POST["testName"])) {
die("text to appear in the textarea box");
}
?>

<body>


<form action="testing.php" method="POST" onsubmit="loadXMLDoc(this.form); return false;">
<input class="command" type="text" name="testName" />
<div><textarea id="testTextarea"></textarea></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mostlikely you have an javascript error in `onsubmit="loadXMLDoc(this.form); return false;"` and then `loadXMLDoc(this.form);`. Because of it the `return false` is not triggered and the form is submitted the regular way. Check the error console to see what goes wrong. At first sight I would say the `this.form` should just be `this` because that is already the form. But there could also be an error in the function itself.

Comment: Timestamp: 31/05/2013 21:49:42
Error: InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
Source File: http://localhost:8082/testing.php
Line: 19

Comment: even if I remove the form action, its the same result

Comment: That's because you can't setRequestHeader() before the connection is open(). The form is only submitting because there's a js error. The form shouldn't submit at all.

Comment: @curtis, I move that down to the line after Open, and removed the action attribute from the form. still same result, so its the javascript submitting it, and its still causing that

Comment: The form shouldn't be submitting unless there is a js error. Doesn't matter if the form has an action or not (it defaults to the current page)

Comment: what is the JS error, I can't see it at all

Comment: there are now no erros in my JS error console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the die() to the top so that nothing else is outputted before die()

```
<?
if (isset($_POST["testName"])) {
die("text to appear in the textarea box");
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("testTextarea").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","testing.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("testName=blah");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>


<form action="testing.php" method="POST" onsubmit="loadXMLDoc(this.form); return false;">
<input class="command" type="text" name="testName" />
<div><textarea id="testTextarea"></textarea></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well $_POST["testName"] isn't set because you are only sending "test". You need to do xmlhttp.send("testName=blah");

Comment: works for me, idk what js error your're getting that's causing the form to submit, that's causing the page to refresh. I think it's best if you don't have a form at all, you can just put inputs without a form, and when your submit button is clicked you call the ajax. The form makes it harder to debug because it submits when there's a js error before return false in onsubmit.

Comment: really? damn.. so what I have above works for you? can you private pastie and link me? By the way, the form is being submitted with enter button only, there isn't a click button

Comment: thanks, don't know how this didn't work for me.. there must be a reason but spent too long already trying to figure it out